# SSRS: Border of a cntrol in a tablix on the last row doesn't show up proper

Tags: reporting-services

I have a strange problem: If I set a border on the controls inside a tablix OR on the row itself, on the last row it seems like cutted in half.
My first thought was the fact, that there is no place after the tablix, but even after moving the other controls away, it's still cut:
[image]

The definition:
[image]

On some cases it might be sufficent just to give the bottom border of the grid some width, but sometimes we need to give just one control a border. Another way is to give the last row-border just double the size, but I guess that can't be the solution?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have borders on both top and bottom of each row. Thats why rest of the rows get double borders. You can either remove the top border from all your rows or add an empty row with just top border on bottom of the tablix.

Comment: Hi Tomi, thanks for Input. I rechecked it and the Border-Definition on each row is: None; ; ; ; Solid 
So the default is None and the bottom is Solid. I tinkered with this arround as well, so I setted every border except Bottom to None, but this didn't work as well.
My main question is: SHOULD the bottom and top have the same size as the other rows or is this behaviour by design?

Comment: They should be the same size. You could try adjusting border width to see if its a rendering issue. And also does the issue exist if you export it to PDF or some other format?

Comment: What you mean with Border-Width? I think it might be a rendering issue, because f.e. on Excel it looks fine, it seems like a problem on PDF:
But I can't believe we're the first Company, which uses a Border in a Grid¿

Comment: By border width I mean how thick is your border? Specially if its some decimal number it could cause issues when the rendering engine tries to convert it to pixels.

Comment: We use most of the time 0.5pt or 1pt, does it work better with other numbers?

Answer (score 1):

In the group properties under "Page Breaks" select the check box "Also at the end of a group and set Report property "ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace" =  True

Comment: Uh thanks, I will try this out for sure the next time